# Ensure Memory Location of Data Members is Before Base Class

Tags: class, memory-alignment

I'm trying to initialize a class B which is derived from base class A.  However, I want the Memory location of B's members to come before those of A's.  The code I have so far is:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A();
    int a;
}
class B : public A {
public:
    B();
    int b;
}
```

However, this causes `b`'s location in memory to come after `a`'s and I need `b` to come before `a` in memory.  Is there a way to do this without copy pasting all of `A` into `B`? (I need `B` to be derived from `A`)